# how to write an insert query in Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, sql-insert

How do I create an insert query in Doctrine that will perform the same function as the following SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO target (tgt_col1, tgt_col2) 
SELECT 'flag' as marker, src_col2 FROM source 
WHERE src_col1='mycriteria'
```

Comment: Well, it looks for me like you are missing the point here. The whole idea of having ORM layer such as Doctrine is that you don't need to (and shouldn't be) writing any SQL queries at all... :-)

Comment: @ADi3ek I've revised my question to clarify what I'm looking for.  I am trying to write a Doctrine query that will select rows from one table and insert them into another table.  I have only included the SQL query in my question as a means of defining what I want to do with Doctrine.

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#native-sql) says:

> If you want to execute DELETE, UPDATE or INSERT statements the Native
>   SQL API cannot be used and will probably throw errors. Use
>   EntityManager#getConnection() to access the native database connection
>   and call the executeUpdate() method for these queries.

#### Examples

```
// Get entity manager from your context.
$em = $this->getEntityManager();

/**
 * 1. Raw query
 */

$query1 = "
    INSERT INTO target (tgt_col1, tgt_col2) 
    SELECT 'flag' as marker, src_col2 FROM source 
    WHERE src_col1='mycriteria'
";

$affectedRows1 = $em->getConnection()->executeUpdate($query1);

/**
 * 2. Query using class metadata.
 */

$metadata = $em->getClassMetadata(Your\NameSpace\Entity\Target::class);
$tableName = $metadata->getTableName();
$niceTitle = $metadata->getColumnName('niceTitle');
$bigDescription = $metadata->getColumnName('bigDescription');

$metadata2 = $em->getClassMetadata(Your\NameSpace\Entity\Source::class);
$table2Name = $metadata2->getTableName();
$smallDescription = $metadata2->getColumnName('smallDescription');

$query2 = "
    INSERT INTO $tableName ($niceTitle, $bigDescription) 
    SELECT 'hardcoded title', $smallDescription FROM $table2Name 
    WHERE $niceTitle = 'mycriteria'
";

$affectedRows2 = $em->getConnection()->executeUpdate($query2);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm still not convinced it's the right approach you are taking but if you *really* need an SQL query to be run for whatever reason you can do that in Doctrine with `$entityManager->createNativeQuery();` function:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Doctrine isn't a tool for query manipulation. The whole idea is to work on Entity level, not the SQL level (tables, etc). Doctrine's 2 `QueryBuilder` doesn't even support `INSERT` operations via DQL.

A small snippet of pseudo code below to illustrate how it can be done in "Doctrine's way":

```
    $qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('s')
        ->from('\Foo\Source\Entity', 's')
        ->where('s.col1 = :col1')
        ->setParameter('col1', 'mycriteria');

    $sourceEntities =  $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    foreach($sourceEntities as $sourceEntity) {
        $targetEntity = new \Foo\Target\Entity();
        $targetEntity->col1 = $sourceEntity->col1;
        $targetEntity->col2 = $sourceEntity->col2;

        $entityManager->persist($targetEntity);
    }

    $entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question.  Here’s the inquiry with all of the SQL references removed: “Using Doctrine, how do you select a subset of records from one table and insert them into another table?”