# How to perform an INSERT INTO SELECT query in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

What’s the best way to perform an INSERT INTO SELECT query in ZF2?

I need to develop a function in ZF2 that selects a subset of records from one table and inserts those records into another table.  If I were programming in SQL, the statement would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO target (tgt_col1, tgt_col2) 
SELECT 'flag' as marker, src_col2 FROM source 
WHERE src_col1='mycriteria'
```

I’ve searched the Doctrine docs and cannot find an INSERT method.  I’ve posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114367/how-to-write-an-insert-query-in-doctrine) under the Doctrine tag and the lack of response leads me to believe that INSERT INTO SELECT is too complex for Doctrine to handle.

In ZF2 it appears that I “could” use`Zend\Db\Sql\Sql`.  However, for that solution, `SELECT` and `INSERT` are two separate functions and it looks like the `INSERT` function only handles a single record at a time.  Therefore, a `Zend\Db\Sql\Sql` solution would require 1) a group of statements to select the data from the source table, 2) perhaps a function to convert that data object to an array, and 3) a `foreach` function to cycle through the data array and individually add each record to the target table via 4) a group of insert statements.  This seems cumbersome compared to the single statement that’s possible in SQL.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

If its `TableGateway` then it definitely works with the latest version of ZF2 i.e. 2.3.2

With reference with the `Album` module -

1. Created a duplicate table of `album` and named it `album_old`.
2. Emptied the `album` table.

So now `album` table is empty and `album_old` has the values.

To copy the records from `album_old` to `album`, did this -

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
....
use Zend\Db\Sql\Insert;

$select = new Select('album_old');
$select->columns(array('artist', 'title', 'cover', 'extra'));

$insert = new Insert();
$insert->into('album');
$insert->columns(array('artist', 'title', 'cover', 'extra'));

$insert->values($select);
//OR
$insert->select($select);

$this->tableGateway->insertWith($insert);
```

All the values from `album_old` were inserted into `album` table.

**Ref:** https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Insert.php
     
Here you will find that the `function values()` can take `array` or `instanceof Select`

and there is a new `select()` function too.