# ZF2 - How do I insert into select?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I am trying to perform an insert into select from a table method in zf2.

The following procedure is what I used as an example.

[How to perform an INSERT INTO SELECT query in ZF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147377/how-to-perform-an-insert-into-select-query-in-zf2)

My table method is contained in a table class in ZF2 which is a separate table in the db from the tables I am trying to insert into.

```
public function addCategoryName($val)
    {
        $data = array ( 
            'CategoryName' => $val);

        $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
        $id = $this->tableGateway->lastInsertValue;

        $on = "categoryid = $id";
        $select = new Select('actionitems');

        $select->columns(array('actionitemid', 'categoryid'))->join('categories', $on, array('actionitemid', 'categoryid'), 'cross'); 

        $adapterInsert = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
            'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
            'database' => 'actionitemmanager',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password'
        ));

        $insert = new Insert();
        $insert->into('actionitemcategories');
        $insert->columns(array('actionitemid', 'categoryid'));
        $insert->values($select);
        //insert with select
        $adapterInsert->insertWith($insert);
    }
```

Neither

> $insert->values($select)

or

> $insert->select($select)

work...

The first attempt gives an error that the $select must be an array, whereas $insert->select($select) gives an error that select() is not a method of Insert.

How can I get this query to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Zend Framework feature you're referencing was [introduced in v2.3](http://framework.zend.com/blog/zend-framework-2-3-0-released.html):

> `Zend\Db\Sql\Insert` can use a `Select` object as the value source (`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`)

I suspect you're using an older version. You can compare `Zend\Db\Sql\Insert` in [v2.2.10](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/release-2.2.10/src/Sql/Insert.php) to [v2.3.0](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/release-2.3.0/src/Sql/Insert.php) to see the different exceptions thrown for invalid arguments.

You should upgrade Zend Framework to v2.3 or greater to use this feature.