# How to reference elements from a joined table in a DQL statement

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I have two entities (`AdminMembers\Entity\Members` and `AdminEvents\Entity\Invitees`) that are joined with a `OneToMany` relationship.  Because the relationship is defined in the entities, I can use the following DQL statement to query the data:

```
$dql = "SELECT i FROM AdminEvents\Entity\Invitees i WHERE i.eventID=$eventID";
```

And, through this configuration I can use statements like `$invitee->getMember()->getMemberLastName()` in my ZF2 view script to get the data from the joined entities.

Now, if I want to sort the data in the DQL statement by fields in `AdminMembers\Entity\Members`, I run into a problem.  The following statement

```
$dql = "SELECT i FROM AdminEvents\Entity\Invitees i WHERE i.eventID=$eventID ORDER BY i.memberLastName, i.memberFirstName";
```

throws the error message

```
Class AdminEvents\Entity\Invitees has no field or association named memberLastName
```

This is because the fields `memberLastName` and `memberFirstName` are defined in `AdminMembers\Entity\Members`.  Although an association does exist, I'm certain I’m just missing some syntax in referencing `memberLastName` and `memberFirstName`.

I know that I can expand the DQL statement to join the entities in the DQL statement, which would allow me to identify the joined table and relate the elements to table identifier.  But, since the tables are already joined in the entity definitions, they shouldn’t have to be joined again.

Is there a special syntax for referencing joined-table entities in the DQL statement without "rejoining" the tables in the statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should join the members entity to be able to sort by its fields. See [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins):

```
$dql = "SELECT i, m FROM AdminEvents\Entity\Invitees i JOIN i.member m WHERE i.eventID=$eventID ORDER BY m. memberLastName, m.memberFirstName";
```

Comment: That appears to be the answer.  It seems counter-intuitive, though.  Before the need to sort the data, it could be accessed with `$invitees = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AdminEvents\Entity\Invitees')->findBy(array('eventID' => $eventID));`, which indicates that Doctrine has already joined the entities.

Comment: Thanks for this, @Vera.  Do you think you can help me with this question: [how to write an insert query in Doctrine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114367/how-to-write-an-insert-query-in-doctrine).